# When reading in a txt matrix, how can i skip first column

Tags: python

I have a file that looks like this:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
3   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
4   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
5   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I want to read in only the 1 and 0 and ignore the top header row and the row name (the first column).

So far I have the header line all set, but how can I skip the skip column. My code so far

```
with open('file') as f:
    next(f) #skips header row
    content = [x.strip('\n') for x in f.readlines()]
```

I'm trying to use only base python and no libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a simple indexing:

```
with open('file') as f:
    next(f)
    content = [x.strip().split()[1:] for x in f]
```

This will give you the splitted zero and ones as a nested list.

If you don't want to split the lines you can still use indexing in order to remove the first character.

```
content = [x[1:].strip() for x in f]
```

Or as a Numpythonic approach you can use the Numpy's `loadtxt()` function:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> np.loadtxt(StringIO(my_string), skiprows=1)[:,1:]
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It's been created to be use :-) (for small data)

Comment: Why would you use it here? You can do the exact same thing iterating over `f`, readlines is for if you actually want to store the lines not just iterate over them. Also split removes whitespace so calling strip is redundant.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Indeed, now this is something lol. Thanks for note.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html),

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0)
matrix = df.as_matrix(df)

print(matrix)
# Output
[[0 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are always 3 spaces between the first and second number you can use this:

```
with open('file1.txt','r') as f:
    next(f)
    content = [x.strip('\n')[4:] for x in f.readlines()]
```

Output:

```
>>> for i in content:
    print(i)


0   1   1   1   1   1   1
0   0   1   1   1   1   1
0   0   0   1   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   0   1   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can *map* *str.split* over the file object :

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    next(f)
    matrix = [list(map(int, row[1:]) for row in map(str.split, f)]
```

If you have a tab delimited file, you can use the *csv* lib:

```
from itertools import islice
import csv
with open("in.txt") as f:
    next(f)
    matrix = [list(map(int, row[1:]) for row in csv.reader(f,delimiter="\t")]
```

Regardless you never need to call *readlines*  unless you want an actual list, you can simply iterate over the file object.

Comment: If you return an iterator it would be a nice approach for large data sets and saving memory. But now that you've converted the iterator to list it would make more problem. Using `itertools` now you have another problem ;-)

Comment: @Kasravand,  `for sub in  (list(map(int, row[1:]) for row in map(str.split, f))` ;)